# How to retrieve list of string dates with BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want some help in creating a small code using BeautifulSoup, for which I want to accomplish two things.

First, I want to be able to retrieve only the dates found in the code below, ex. findAll `<td>02/02/2011</td>`, then store it in a list. My problem is, that because there are several `td` tags, I don't know how to retrieve the date strings specifically.

Second, after the list of dates is retrieved, I will then have two variables. One variable contains only one date, and the other variable contains list of all dates. For instance, `date_lst_single = "<td>01/04/2011</td>"` and `date_lst_all = ["LIST OF ALL DATES"]`.

Lastly, I want to be able to create some kind of Find condition for which I will use datetime dependency, but just need the logic behind it. Whatever the date found in `date_lst = <td>02/02/2011</td>` in this case 02/02/2011, I want to find ONLY the date that comes before it. In the code below for instance, the previous date before such date is `<td>01/04/2011</td>`, then retrieve the date and store in new variable.

```
 <td>10/24/2011</td>,
 <td><span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">17</span> - 31 - 33</td>,
 <span class="match">11</span>,
 <span class="match">12</span>,
 <span class="match">17</span>,
 <td>8,210</td>,
 <td>$10.50</td>,
 <tr><td>06/15/2011</td><td>1 - 7 - <span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">17</span></td><td>15,369</td><td>$6.50</td></tr>,
 <td>06/15/2011</td>,
 <td>1 - 7 - <span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">17</span></td>,
 <span class="match">11</span>,
 <span class="match">12</span>,
 <span class="match">17</span>,
 <td>15,369</td>,
 <td>$6.50</td>,
 <tr class="alt"><td>01/04/2011</td><td><span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">20</span> - 21 - 27</td><td>10,752</td><td>$15.00</td></tr>,
 <td>01/04/2011</td>,
 <td><span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">20</span> - 21 - 27</td>,
 <span class="match">11</span>,
 <span class="match">12</span>,
 <span class="match">20</span>,
 <td>10,752</td>,
 <td>$15.00</td>,
 <tr><td>09/24/2009</td><td>2 - 3 - <span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">17</span></td><td>11,406</td><td>$7.50</td></tr>,
 <td>09/24/2009</td>,
 <td>2 - 3 - <span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">17</span></td>,
 <span class="match">11</span>,
 <span class="match">12</span>,
 <span class="match">17</span>,
 <td>11,406</td>,
 <td>$7.50</td>,
 <tr class="alt"><td>08/08/2009</td><td><span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">20</span> - 26 - 28 - <span class="match">30</span></td><td>10,267</td><td>$11.00</td></tr>,
 <td>08/08/2009</td>,
 <td><span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">20</span> - 26 - 28 - <span class="match">30</span></td>,
 <span class="match">12</span>,
 <span class="match">20</span>,
 <span class="match">30</span>,
 <td>10,267</td>,
 <td>$11.00</td>,
 <tr><td>05/05/2009</td><td>8 - <span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">20</span> - 26</td><td>11,260</td><td>$8.00</td></tr>,
 <td>05/05/2009</td>,
 <td>8 - <span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">20</span> - 26</td>,
 <span class="match">11</span>,
 <span class="match">12</span>,
 <span class="match">20</span>,
 <td>11,260</td>,
 <td>$8.00</td>,
 <tr class="alt"><td>04/07/2009</td><td>10 - <span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - 16 - <span class="match">17</span></td><td>11,163</td><td>$8.50</td></tr>,
 <td>04/07/2009</td>,
 <td>10 - <span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - 16 - <span class="match">17</span></td>,
 <span class="match">11</span>,
 <span class="match">12</span>,
 <span class="match">17</span>,
 <td>11,163</td>,
 <td>$8.50</td>,
 <tr><td>01/31/2009</td><td>3 - <span class="match">17</span> - <span class="match">20</span> - <span class="match">30</span> - 34</td><td>10,086</td><td>$11.50</td></tr>,
 <td>01/31/2009</td>,
 <td>3 - <span class="match">17</span> - <span class="match">20</span> - <span class="match">30</span> - 34</td>,
 <span class="match">17</span>,
 <span class="match">20</span>,
 <span class="match">30</span>,
 <td>10,086</td>,
 <td>$11.50</td>,
 <tr class="alt"><td>08/06/2008</td><td>4 - <span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">30</span> - 32</td><td>9,497</td><td>$11.00</td></tr>,
 <td>08/06/2008</td>,
 <td>4 - <span class="match">11</span> - <span class="match">12</span> - <span class="match">30</span> - 32</td>,
 <span class="match">11</span>,
 <span class="match">12</span>,
 <span class="match">30</span>,
 <td>9,497</td>,
 <td>$11.00</td>,
```

UPDATE:

In case this may help someone else, the last part of the code I had requested is as follow. I joined with the help I received on this post.

```
#Input date
five_to_date = ['09/01/2016']
def isDate(tag):
    if tag.name=='td':
        return bool(re.match('\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d', tag.text))
    else:
        return False

#store in list
tds_three_five = three_five.find_all(isDate)
dates_three = [p.text for p in tds_three_five]
#target date
dates_three_cnv = [datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y').date() for x in 
dates_three]

for i in range(1):
    _lst_all_threefive = []
    for j in dates_three_cnv:
        if j < five_to_date:
            _lst_all_threefive.append(j)
    three_five_to_calc = _lst_all_threefive[0] # we only want one date
#Perform calculation of input date minus target date.
delta = five_to_date - three_five_to_calc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recover the dates in `td` tags in this way.

```
>>> HTML = open('trial.htm').read()
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> import re
>>> def isDate(tag):
...     if tag.name=='td':
...         return bool(re.match('\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d', tag.text))
...     else:
...         return False
... 
>>> tds = soup.find_all(isDate)
>>> tds
[<td>10/24/2011</td>, <td>06/15/2011</td>, <td>06/15/2011</td>, <td>01/04/2011</td>, <td>01/04/2011</td>, <td>09/24/2009</td>, <td>09/24/2009</td>, <td>08/08/2009</td>, <td>08/08/2009</td>, <td>05/05/2009</td>, <td>05/05/2009</td>, <td>04/07/2009</td>, <td>04/07/2009</td>, <td>01/31/2009</td>, <td>01/31/2009</td>, <td>08/06/2008</td>, <td>08/06/2008</td>]
>>> dates = [_.text for _ in tds]
>>> dates
['10/24/2011', '06/15/2011', '06/15/2011', '01/04/2011', '01/04/2011', '09/24/2009', '09/24/2009', '08/08/2009', '08/08/2009', '05/05/2009', '05/05/2009', '04/07/2009', '04/07/2009', '01/31/2009', '01/31/2009', '08/06/2008', '08/06/2008']
```

I'm not altogether sure what the rest of your question means. However, I suspect you can glean what you need from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) (or BeautifulSoup with lxml) to parse your file. Then use an XPath expression to select all the `<td>`

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(path)
td_nodes = tree.xpath('//td')
```

Then, you can define a function to identify the nodes with valid date:

```
def is_date(node):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(node.text, '%m/%d/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

You can use this function to find the date attached to a `td` node:

```
nodes_with_date = {node: is_date(node) for node in td_nodes}
```

The list of `td` with dates can be extracted like this:

```
date_list = [node for node, date in nodes_with_date.items()
             if date]
```

The list of `td` preceding a given date is:

```
date_list = [node for node, date in nodes_with_date.items()
             if date and date < given_date]
```